# I've tried "float" and "margin-top" but the image will not align with the text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm making a product landing page and I'm trying to make it so that there's a paragraph with an image on the right. I put `float: right;` but it doesn't seem to work. It worked with my navbar though.

Here's the code:

```css
.device {
width: 400px;
height: 500px;
margin-bottom: 0x;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
<h2 id="the-benefits" class="info-header">The benefits<h2>
<p id="the-benefits"> Text about benefits.</p>
<img class="device" src="image.jpg" alt="text">
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your desire result?

Comment: I want to have text next to an image on the right. [text][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

float right is designed to do what you want - to float a picture on the right and let any text not just sit to the left of it but to flow underneath it if it is too long.

However, by the time you have the h2 and the div painted it's too late as the content has moved onto a new line. If you put the float before them then the system knows what space to allow for the image and the h2 and div will sit to its left.

```css
.device {
width: 400px;
height: 500px;
margin-bottom: 0x;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
<img class="device" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/400/300" alt="text">
<h2 id="the-benefits" class="info-header">The benefits<h2>
<p id="the-benefits"> Text about benefits.</p>
</div>
```